# Xamarin Carousel View

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I am trying to use alexrainman Carousel control:
https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView

I have not been able to make it work

Here is my XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions;assembly=CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions"
    x:Class="QueryPoint.Views.ImageViewer">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
          <controls:CarouselViewControl x:Name="carImages" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding Url}" />
              </DataTemplate>
            </controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
          </controls:CarouselViewControl>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is my .cs file:

public partial class ImageViewer : ContentPage
{
    ObservableCollection ListImages;

```
public ImageViewer()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    carImages.ItemsSource = null;
}

public ImageViewer(List<ImageEntity> list)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    carImages.Position = 0;
    ListImages = new ObservableCollection<ImageEntity>();
    foreach (ImageEntity img in list)
        ListImages.Add(img);
    carImages.ItemsSource = ListImages;

}
```

Class is:

```
public class ImageEntity
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

I don't get an error, it just doesn't show anything.

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Try to add `VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"` to the stacklayout and to the carousel

Comment: @Gusman Thanks that did the trick...